# How to use a SSD as cache on Windows Server?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, filesystems, storage, cache, storage-spaces

I have Windows Server 2022 2xHDD and 2xNVMe

Can I use NVMe like cache? Maybe Storage Spaces or other app? I want to use half of NVMe space directly for VMs and half of NVMe space for cache of HDD. What is the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

Check two options:

1. Storage Spaces tiering . I did it for Windows 2016 and Windows 2019 and don’t have experience in Windows 2022. Here is reference for configuration with PowerShell - https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/configure-a-resilient-volume-on-windows-server-2016-using-storage-spaces
   As advantage – you’ll will not lose usable space of “cache” storage.
2. Storage Bus Cache feature.  It enables read/write NVMe cache for HDD storage. It is possible to choose percentage of NVMe capacity dedicated for cache.  Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/storage-spaces-storage-bus-cache

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer!
1) As I tried, for the first option we should dedicate one disk for system, right? So if I have 2xHDD and 2xNVMe - there is no adequate options? Because right configurations is 2 mirrors? 
2) Did you try this option? I tried, but does not work for me, will try with 2019 Server, thank you

Now trying with Primo Cache. Working great, but Im scare about 3-party app) Here we can user even RAM. But so scare for prod  especially without ECC.